# Theorem weak Hilbert

Tags: algebraic-geometry

If $ I $ is a proper ideal of $ K [x_1, \ldots, x_n] = F $ then $ V (I) \neq \emptyset$.
dm: 
I want to use that $ J = \langle x_1-a_1, \ldots, a_n x_n \rangle $ is a maximal ideal of $ F $.
If I prove that $ J \subseteq I$ then you would have $ I = J $ for $ J \subset I \subset F$ then $ I = J $ or $ I = F $ but the second case is given as $ I $ is proper. Then $ V (I) = \{(a_1, \ldots, a_n) \} \neq \emptyset$. 
I hope a suggestion that $ J \subset I$.

Comment: Is $K$ algebraically closed?

Comment: k algebraically closed

Comment: Any proper ideal $I$ is contained in some maximal ideal $J$. Every maximal ideal is of the form $\langle x_1-a_1, ..., x_n -a_n \rangle$ since $K$ is algebraically closed by Nullstellensatz. That implies $(a_1,...,a_n) \in V(J)$. Since $I\subseteq J$, we have $V(J) \subseteq V(I)$, therefore $(a_1,...,a_n)\in V(I)$.